# subtracting 4 columns of one csv file to another csv file and want output in Text file -Python

Tags: python, csv

I have two csv file both have same number of COULMN and ROW in same format...As showed below..

CSV 1

```
 Row0    Row1       Row2     Row3    Row4    Row5    Row6   Row7
NIFTY   20170901    9.08    9937.65 9937.65 9937.65 9937.65 55600
NIFTY   20170901    9.16    9938.1  9938.1  9916.7  9917.5  58
NIFTY   20170901    9.17    9917.85 9919.2  9916    9917.6  58
NIFTY   20170901    9.18    9918.35 9918.75 9914.45 9915.3  58
NIFTY   20170901    9.19    9914.3  9914.8  9910.1  9910.55 58
```

CSV 2

```
Row0        Row1       Row2     Row3    Row4    Row5    Row6   Row7
NIFTY_F1    20170901    9.16    9945.3  9954.85 9941.8  9942.1  132300
NIFTY_F1    20170901    9.17    9942.5  9945.45 9942.5  9944.75 60300
NIFTY_F1    20170901    9.18    9944.6  9944.85 9942.05 9943.5  41625
NIFTY_F1    20170901    9.19    9943.3  9943.3  9937.55 9938.2  46425
NIFTY_F1    20170901    9.20    9938.75 9945.9  9938.75 9945.4  28650
NIFTY_F1    20170901    9.21    9945.9  9965    9945.9  9958.55 143250
```

So I want to do like this ,

```
  c3=Row3(CSV2) - Row3(CSV1) ,c4= Row4(CSV2) - Row4(CSV1) , c5=Row5(CSV2) - Row5(CSV1) , 
c6=Row6(CSV2) - Row6(CSV1) .....
```

do this and make new text file which has

```
Row0 , Row1 , Row2, C3, C4 ,C5 , C6 ,Row7
```

Row0,Row1,Row2 can be from anyone nd Row7 has to be from CSV2.

How to do this?? don't know how to start and do this in python.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

General tips, first you have to read in both of your csv files and parse them into manipulatable arrays (either parse them using the `csv` [package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) into `numpy` arrays, or make use of `numpy.genfromtxt` [package/method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) to read directly to arrays). Next, you can simply just subtract the respective columns from the read-in datasets and assign to a new array. This can then be output using any number of methods (including the `csv.writer()` method).